# I cant get a field on report from a view

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

When I get a field, this work good.

But, when get a field from a 'VIEW', is a problem because the code of a VIEW is:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tabla_clientes AS
SELECT id_cliente,nombre, CONCAT('$ ',FORMAT(monto_a_favor,0), '???'), CONCAT('$ ',FORMAT(calcular_monto_por_cobrar_cliente(id_cliente),0)) 
FROM cliente;
```

When I compile this. Appears errors from the name of fields.

```
Description                                            |  Object
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements   | ${CONCAT('$ ',FORMAT(monto_a_favor,0)}
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens            | ${CONCAT('$ ',FORMAT(monto_a_favor,0)}
Syntax error on token ",", delete this token           | ${CONCAT('$ ',FORMAT(monto_a_favor,0)}
```

If I change the name at this field appears other error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this..

Using a ALIAS after each field :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tabla_clientes AS
SELECT id_cliente,nombre AS id_cliente, CONCAT('$ ',FORMAT(monto_a_favor,0), '???') AS monto_favor, CONCAT('$ ',FORMAT(calcular_monto_por_cobrar_cliente(id_cliente),0)) AS monto_calculado 
FROM cliente;
```

I call the fields from Alias.